# Entitiy Framework, add index to column of complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

EF 6.1 added the new `IndexAttribute`, however, if I have a complex type `Address` which is used in multiple entities (e.g. `Person` and `Facility`) and I want to setup an index on `Person.Address.Street`, what's the proper way to do that?

Obviously putting the `IndexAttribute` on the `Address.Street` property cannot work. Is there a fluent configuration option available? Is this scenario not supported at all? Will it be supported shortly?

Comment: Same here. It seems we need to remove other indexes in migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the game but I have a similar situation and put an Index attribute on every property in the complex type - checking the table afterwards, it appears they have all been added as expected.